# Kairos subscription for android using Rapid API

Tags: java, android, api, face-recognition, kairos-api

I am using Kairos from Rapid API platform, but the rapid api only provided me with a api_key. How can I get the app_id for kairos using the platform of rapid api?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a little bit more information.

RapidAPI provides you with several [SDK implementations](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/getting-started-with-rapidapi-sdks).

In terms of how to use their API Kairo also provides a [tutorial](https://rapidapi.com/blog/face-recognition-api-javascript/)